# NestJs With TypeORM(0.3x) Custom Repository Transaction Problem

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I am using NestJs by creating a custom repository as follows.

**iuser.repository.ts**

```js
import { UserEntity } from "../entity/user-entity";

export interface IUserRepository {
    findByEmail(email: string): Promise<UserEntity>
}
```

**user.repository.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { InjectRepository } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { UserEntity } from "src/user/domain/entity/user-entity";
import { IUserRepository } from "src/user/domain/repository/iuser.repository";
import { Repository } from "typeorm";

@Injectable()
export class UserRepository extends Repository<UserEntity> implements IUserRepository {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
        private readonly userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>
    ) {
        super(UserEntity, userRepository.manager)
    }

    async findByEmail(email: string): Promise<UserEntity> {
        return await this.userRepository
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .where('email = :email', { email })
            .getOne();
    }
}
```

And the method I tried in the service is as follows
[image]

When I run **withRepository(this.userRepository)** with no error indication, the following error appears

```js
       if (this.isReleased) throw new QueryRunnerAlreadyReleasedError()
                                   ^
QueryRunnerAlreadyReleasedError: Query runner already released. Cannot run queries anymore.
```

This is the log of **queryRunner.manager.withRepository(this.userRepository)**

```js
UserRepository {
  target: [class UserEntity],
  manager: undefined,
  queryRunner: undefined,
  userRepository: Repository {
    target: [class UserEntity],
    manager: EntityManager {
      '@instanceof': Symbol(EntityManager),
      repositories: [Map],
      treeRepositories: [],
      plainObjectToEntityTransformer: PlainObjectToNewEntityTransformer {},
      connection: [DataSource]
    },
    queryRunner: undefined
  }
}
```

I understood that **withRepository** creates an instance of a custom Repository and passes the manager of the current transaction.

I'm very curious about the method, but I have no idea how to use it.

How can I use a custom repository in a transaction in the same way as above, other than the getRepository().extend method in the TypeORM doc?